# How to add woocommerce product add manually and assign user to it?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have created order By code

```
$order_data = array(
            'post_name'     => 'order-' . date_format($order_date, 'M-d-Y-hi-a'), //'order-jun-19-2014-0648-pm'
            'post_type'     => 'shop_order',
            'post_title'    => 'Order &ndash; ' . date_format($order_date, 'F d, Y @ h:i A'), //'June 19, 2014 @ 07:19 PM'
            'post_status'   => 'wc-completed',
            'ping_status'   => 'closed',
            'post_excerpt'  => '',
            'post_author'   => $user_id,
            'post_date'     => date_format($order_date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s e'), //'order-jun-19-2014-0648-pm'
            'comment_status' => 'open'
        );
        $order_id = wp_insert_post( $order_data, true );
```

After that i have add items by following code.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items (`order_item_name`,`order_item_type`,`order_id`) VALUES ('$item_name','line_item',$order_id)";
                $prods = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

Now i want to add user to that (who order this item).
So how can i do this.Please suggest me solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce uses the post_author field as customer (who ordered the item).
So in your code $user_id is the customer. $user_id should be the user id of the current user.

Alternatively you can use wc_create_order() method to create orders. You can refer this [example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/212885)

Comment: Is there a way to change this flow?